# Why does not image cleanup policy work in Gitlab?

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-api

I have following GitLab cleanup policy

[image]

I assumed that the images would be cleared. And If would send a get query like

```py
headers = {"PRIVATE-TOKEN": TOKEN}

url = "https://.../api/v4/projects/" + PROJECT_ID + "/registry/repositories"
```

I had to get something like

```
"cleanup_policy_started_at": "2020-01-10T15:40:57.391Z"
```

But instead I receive

```
cleanup_policy_started_at': None
```

Why? Should I turn something on?

Answer (score 1):

You need to explicitly set the tags to `.*`

Comment: if nothing typed, there is a placeholder that says .* - but that does not work.

Comment: Fortunately, everything works fine. I don't know why the required information wasn't displayed in the query